# How to pass variables as the name of array into function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

From my DOM element, I let the user choose a state.

In my code I go:

```
 var State = $("select[name=state1]").val();
```

So if AZ was selected, the ouput would be `State == "AZ"`

Then I have arrays for every state so for example:

```
var AZ =[[1],[2]];
```

And I fill each array with some data.
Then I try to do a calculation that looks like this:

```
var ABC = 25 * State[0][1];
```

However, the variable `state` isn't an array. I want `state` replaced by the chosen one,  for example it might be `AZ` so I actually want to calculate...

```
 var ABC = 25 * AZ[0][1];
```

Any ideas on how I can pass the value of `State` into last equation automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest assigning your state values a little differently:

```
var states = {
    AZ: [[1],[2]],
    //and so on
};
```

Then you can do

```
var ABC = 25 * states[State][0][1];
```

Comment: I dont understand what `AZ: [[1][2]]` does. State returns "AZ" from the DOM and then I want to call element `AZ[1][2]` by typing `State[1][2]`

Comment: I forgot a comma. Edited the answer, but it's the same idea as @artm's. I'm just slower typing through the stack exchange app. lol

Comment: Basically the bottommost expression expands to 25 * the 2nd element of the array associated with attribute "AZ" of `states` (25 * 2)

Comment: Nice, I think that might work, I will test it at home tonight.

Comment: Your solution has a wierd thing. When I do `var states = {
    AZ: [[1],[4]],` and I print AZ in console it has 2 rows but only 1 column.

Comment: `AZ` is an array, that contains 2 arrays, with one element each. What were you expecting?

Comment: The nested arrays need to be 2 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: So, `{AZ: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}`?

Comment: if I wanted to change just one of those values later, how could I do it?

Like if I wanted "5" to become "green"

Comment: I think you should read about how objects and arrays work in JavaScript. Let's say you want to change the 4 to a 7. You would do `states.AZ[1][0] = 7;` or `states["AZ"][1][0] = 7;`

Comment: hey so I think your method works and I am able to call it using

`states[State][1][4]`

Answer (score 1):

Change your state to be an object to contain state arrays:

```
var state = { AZ : [[1],[2]], OS : [[3], [4]] };
var abc = 25 * state["AZ"][0]
```

Comment: What is OS? and what does the `:` do here?

Comment: I'll take a guess and say it's an arbitrary state abbreviation data point used just as an example... And `:` assigns the array to the object's named data point.

Comment: @Badrush Just like jTitus said, 'OS' could be anything, just an example of another state, and : is how you assign values to object's properties.

Comment: Okay, but if I am defining state as `var State = $("select[name=state1]").val();` I cannot make state a bunch of arrays. I basically get a string from the user, which I need to use to find the array whose name matches that string.

Comment: @Badrush `var stateValues = { AZ : [[1],[2]], OS : [[3], [4]] }; var State = $("select[name=state1]").val(); var abc = 25 * stateValues[State][0]`

Comment: `state = { AZ : [[1],[2]], OS : [[3], [4]] };` So here, it says `state` contains a matrix `AZ` with 2 rows, 4 columns.... and OS has 4 rows, 5 columns?

Comment: Your solution has a wierd thing. When I do `var states = { AZ: [[1],[4]],` and I print AZ in console it has 2 rows but only 1 column.

Comment: @Badrush Have a look at how arrays work in javascript. `var a = [[73, 83], [46]];` means an array of two arrays, not dimensions. `a[0]` will give you the first array `[73, 83]`, `a[1]` the 2nd array `[46]`.

Comment: @artm how can I then call a specific element in the 2nd array then? `a[1][[0],[2]]` ?

Comment: @Badrush `a[1]` gives you the 2nd array, to get the 2nd element inside the 2nd array you use `a[1][1]`. To get the 3rd element of the first array you use `a[0][2]`. To get the 4th element of the 2nd array you use `a[1][3]`. Like I said, have a look at how arrays in JS work.

Comment: Okay but I don't want to deal with arrays that have only 1 dimension, I want an array with 2 rows.

Comment: @Badrush http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript